# trouble swapping divs from li click event

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and am having a hard time trying to get something very simple to work. I have the following basic html:

first I have a list of buttons

```
<div id="my_menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="" class='1'">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="" class='2'">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="" class='3'">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Then I have some divs:

```
<div id="ref_1">Message 1</div>
<div id="ref_2">Message 2</div>
<div id="ref_3">Message 3</div>
```

Now I simply want to click a link and show the appropriate message while hiding the others.

First, I set the default message and link state:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ref_1').show();
$('#ref_1').siblings('div').hide();
$('#my_menu li a.1).parent('li').addClass("active");
});
```

So far, so good. Next, I try to setup the click events on the list

```
$("#my_menu li a").click(function(){
alert('you have a click event');
return false;
});
```

I can't get a click event. I also tried:

```
$("#my_menu li").each( function(){
alert('you have a click event');
return false;
});              
});
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `$('#my_menu li a.1)` should be `$('#my_menu li a.1')`. If it's already`$('#my_menu li a.1')` then I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because of this line, javascript stop running

```
$('#my_menu li a.1).parent('li').addClass("active");
});
```

So all js after this line will not be executed.
Fix by add a single quote

```
$('#my_menu li a.1').parent('li').addClass("active");
});
```

If i was you, I will do like this

```
<div id="links">
   <ul id="list">
       <li id="link1"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="display">text 1</a></li>
       <li id="link2"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="display">text 1</a></li>
       <li id="link3"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="display">text 1</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<div class="hide" id="ref_1">Message 1</div>
<div class="hide" id="ref_2">Message 2</div>
<div class="hide" id="ref_3">Message 3</div>
<script>
$(".hide").each(function(){$(this).hide()});
$('ul#list li').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(".hide").each(function(){$(this).hide()});
        $('#ref_' + $(this).attr("id").substring(4)).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That line appears valid. It works and I can put a working line after it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your fully expanded message ...I'm new to this site. Hey, thanks! I'm going to give this a try.

Comment: Bang Dao, thanks again for your help on this. Your code helped me spot what what going wrong. You placed all of your script in your example after the list and the divs, which made me realize that my list-click events where somehow out of execution order because your clicks where working.

Going back to my original code, I realized that if I'm going to use the ready() method, I have to write all my code for this within it's scope, otherwise the click methods end up getting written first and then overwritten by the code for the setup.

Answer (score 0):

Your class attributes look fishy for a start:

```
<li><a href="" class='1'">Link 1</a></li>
```

Should be:

```
<li><a href="" class="1">Link 1</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final working solution. The problem was I was writing the click functions outside of the scope of the ready() method, so my default setup must have been overwriting my attempts to write click functions for the list.

Thanks for the help!

```
<script>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //default setup
    $('#ref_1').show();
    $('#ref_1').siblings('div').hide();
    $('#my_menu li a.1').parent('li').addClass("active");

    $('#my_menu li a').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $(this).parent('li').addClass("active");
            $(this).parent('li').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
            $('#ref_'+$(this).attr("class")).show();
            $('#ref_'+$(this).attr("class")).siblings('div').hide();
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

```
</script>

<div id="my_menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class='1'>Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class='2'>Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class='3'>Link 3</a></li>      
</ul>
</div>

<div id="ref_1">message 1</div>
<div id="ref_2">message 2</div>
<div id="ref_3">message 3</div>
```